# How to delete a record with CodeIgniter and Datamapper if the primary key is named anything but "id"?

Tags: php, codeigniter, primary-key, datamapper

I have a table named `usuario`, an entity with the same name, and the primary key is named `idusuario`. I can't delete it since the primary key isn't named "id". Is it possible to circumvent this limitation somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$this->db->delete('usuario', array('idusuario' => $value));
```

According to [CodeIgniter's Active Record documentation:](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#delete)

> The first parameter is the table name, the second is the where
>   clause. You can also use the where() or or_where() functions instead
>   of passing the data to the second parameter of the function:

Comment: That did the trick. I was expecting an answer on how to do it with Datamapper, but you showed me the simpler way. hehe
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. You should always try to use Active Record as far as possible for all Selects, inserts etc. It sanitizes inputs automatically, protecting you from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Datamapper doesn't use Active Record internally?

Comment: I wouldn't be sure. I've never used it

Comment: I'll scope it out. EDIT: Done. It indeed uses Active Record. `datamapper.php  Line 1713: $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);`

Answer (score 2):

DataMapper, as of the current release, requires the primary key to be called 'id', and it must be an integer. This is hardcoded, no way around it (if you want to use DataMapper).

This restriction will be removed in version 2.